# How do I change permissions for files in the /boot folder using Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspbian, permissions

I know this has been asked and answered before, but I've tried all the fixes and it still won't work. I need to edit one file in the /boot folder, I've tried all these from a root command line:

chmod a=rwx /boot/file.name

sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /boot/file.name

chown -R pi /boot/file.name

The first two commands do nothing and the file permissions have not been edited. The last command returns the error "operation not permitted." I created the file I'm trying to edit permissions for, also through a root command line. Any help would be appreciated.

Results of ls -la

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ls -la
total 180
drwxr-xr-x 21 pi   pi    4096 Jul 31 16:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 10 04:17 ..
-rw-------  1 pi   pi     319 Jul 31 16:05 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi     220 Apr 10 04:17 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi    3512 Apr 10 04:17 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  6 pi   pi    4096 Jul 31 15:19 .cache
drwx------ 14 pi   pi    4096 Jul 31 15:25 .config
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Jul 31 16:52 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  5 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 04:52 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Jul 31 15:24 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi   11796 May 27  2016 duckpi.sh
drwx------  2 pi   pi    4096 Jul 31 15:19 .gconf
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi   11640 May 27  2016 g_hid.ko
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 05:11 .gstreamer-0.10
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi   pi   15004 Jul 31 15:28 hid-gadget-test
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi   10887 May 27  2016 hid-gadget-test.c
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 04:52 .local
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 05:10 Music
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 05:10 Pictures
drwx------  3 pi   pi    4096 Jul 31 15:19 .pki
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi     675 Apr 10 04:17 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 05:10 Public
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 04:52 python_games
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi    4063 May 27  2016 readme.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Jul 31 15:27 rspiducky-master
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 05:10 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 05:10 .themes
drwx------  4 pi   pi    4096 Jul 31 15:25 .thumbnails
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi    5796 May 27  2016 usleep
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi     107 May 27  2016 usleep.c
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 05:10 Videos
drwx------  3 pi   pi    4096 Apr 10 05:13 .vnc
-rw-------  1 pi   pi      56 Jul 31 16:03 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1 pi   pi     353 Jul 31 16:03 .xsession-errors
-rw-------  1 pi   pi     353 Apr 10 07:49 .xsession-errors.old

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output of ls -la?

Comment: What happens if you use sudo with the last one? and why are you using the -R option on a file, not a directory?

Comment: Using sudo with the last one returns the same "operation not permitted" error. I've tried using -R on the entire directory and it gives me the same error. Can you give me the specific command you'd like me to try?

Comment: edit your question and add the output of this command ls -la. Then run this sudo chown pi:pi /boot/file.name (obviously changing the name of the file to match yours) and add the results to your question. Are you trying to change the owner or the permissions, or both?

Comment: `chmod -R` would apply recursive changes, but you appear to be using on a file. `FAT32` does not support `x` permission, apparent permissions are inherited from the mount point.

Comment: Edited, and sudo chown pi:pi /boot/file.name returns the same error message. I'm only trying to edit a text file, so either owner or permissions, whichever one lets me do this.